# Not Getting Line Items from "prebuilt-invoice"

Tags: .net-6.0, azure-form-recognizer

If I submit an invoice in the Form Recognizer Studio, it finds and presents the line items from the invoice.

If I then take that same invoice and submit it using the code from the Form Recognizer Studio, I do not get the line items in the JSON. I do get all the other data.

Any idea why?

```
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.AI.FormRecognizer" Version="4.0.0" />
```

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessInvoice(IFormFile pdfInvoice) {
        try {
            string endpoint = "https://xxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";
            string key = "xxx";
            AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(key);
            DocumentAnalysisClient client = new DocumentAnalysisClient(new Uri(endpoint), credential);
            using var stream = pdfInvoice.OpenReadStream();
            AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-invoice", stream);
            AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;

            return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: According to my understanding, it looks like they have added a piece of code(for-loop) to enumerate all the Invoice items list in the FR studio. Have you tried the code similar to the Form recognizer studio in C# as well?

Answer (score 0):

@VasaviLankipalle you are correct. What I was looking for was that the `AnalyzeResult` JSON would just include the line items without the extra step of iterating through them.

I did end up iterating through the line items and building my own JSON to send back from the controller.